# Okta integration with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway, okta

I have been tasked with integrating an existing JavaScript application with Okta.

This application requires access to certain resources on Amazon's AWS API Gateway. The API-Gateway-generated SDK requires an access key and a secret access key for which we would prefer to use temporary credentials.

According to AWS documentation, an assertion is required to make a call to [AWS's AssumeRoleWithSAML in order to retrieve temporary credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_saml.html).

I've tried the following Okta resources, but have been unable to determine how to obtain an assertion using JavaScript:

- [AWS SAML Integration with Okta](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/28861996-AWS-SAML-integration-with-Okta):
  This setup allows for logging in to the AWS Console.
- [The Okta Sign-in Widget](http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/okta_sign-in_widget.html): Using the widget, I've been unable to find an assertion in what is being returned.
- [Okta API/SDK](http://developer.okta.com/docs/sdk/core/api.html): A JavaScript API/SDK is not listed.

I have found a few Python implementations that return temporary access keys, but haven't found any examples or documentation describing a JavaScript approach with Okta.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example application showing how to integrate Okta with Amazon S3 in JavaScript, using the Okta Sign-In Widget: https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-aws

This example application is based on Amazon's [JavaScript in the Browser](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/) sample application, but authenticates against Okta using OpenID Connect instead of using Facebook, as Amazon's sample application does.

> Please note that the current version of the Okta Sign-In Widget (1.7.0) includes the `xhr` library which conflicts with Amazon's JavaScript SDK. This will be fixed in version 1.9.0 of the Okta Sign-In Widget, which removes `xhr`. In the meantime, the example in the okta-oidc-aws repo ships with a custom version of the widget that has `xhr` disabled.

The [GitHub repository for the okta-oidc-aws sample](https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-aws) has full details on getting the example working.

At a high level, the important parts are as follows:

1. Get an [OpenID Connect `id_token`](https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2013/04/04/ID-Tokens) from Okta.
2. Use the [WebIdentityCredentials class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WebIdentityCredentials.html) to exchange the Okta `id_token` for an AWS IAM Role. This is known as "[Web Identity Federation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html)".

The code that does this is below, and is copied straight from the [sample.html](https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-aws/blob/276b8f02eb4f99dd000017c763ed045471bb095c/sample.html#L101-L118) file in the example:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.WebIdentityCredentials({
    RoleArn: AWS_ROLE_ARN,
    WebIdentityToken: res.idToken
});
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error creating AWS Web Identity: " + err);
        return;
    }
    bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME
        }
    });
    oktaLoginContainer.style.display = 'none';
    uploadDialog.style.display = 'block';
    listObjs();
});
```